# Find duplicate files using C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, hashtable

I am attempting to write a C program that searches for duplicate files, groups the files, and then returns any files that are duplicates. The user can enter either a file path or specify files to check for using from the command line (argc). I am going to use stat() to traverse the system, and I know I need to use a hash table to bin the files. However, I am a bit lost on what to do to actually check if the files are repeats.

I know there are already programs that will do this for you, but this is an academic exercise that I need to complete. I am not looking for the coding answer, just a higher level answer on how I should go about solving the problem. Any feedback is appreciated, including any suggestions other than the ones I have listed above (again, I have to write this program from scratch).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. What do you plan to use a hash table for? Is that a specific requirement? Are you thinking of hashing the file contents with a crypto hash function?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I was planning on using the hash table to bin the files that were duplicates, so I could then access them the bins to output. This isn't a specific requirement, just a suggestion from the instructor.

Comment: Start out by reading up on functions like MD5 and SHA1.

Comment: Yeah, @DavidSchwartz 's suggestion is the way to go. Rather than a diff-like program that explicitly compares files, just get every file's md5 hash, sort that list of hash strings (carrying along corresponding file path/names), and then run through the sorted list looking for md5[i+1]=md5[i]. The md5 hash is a bit long-winded if you have to program it yourself from scratch, so maybe a simpler hash is okay if it's just for an exercise.

Comment: @RoadRunner, nothing thus far. I have only been reading up on how to attempt to tackle the problem. I did run across finddup, which you can download, and that seemed to use MD5 and SHA1 like others have suggested.